# Can I fly with a video card in my carry-on?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, electronic-items

I'm flying from New York to Romania with Turkish Airlines. I've searched everywhere. Am I allowed to bring a video card (original box + receipt) in my carry on?

Comment: I've heard some stories about confiscated video cards and I got a little scared thats why I'm asking

Comment: Hi Andrei.  It's unclear if you're asking about SECURITY or CUSTOMS issues?  If you mean SECURITY, no problem at all.  When they say "remove your laptop" just take it out and leave it in the tray, it's a non-issue.

Comment: I'm asking about both. I've only flew just 2 times and I don't realy know the whole procedure

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  It is allowed, as are laptops and most other consumer electronic devices.  You can carry an Xbox One with you without issue.

The only complication you might face is TSA, and the equivalent at IST, considering it a "large electronic device" in which case, it will have to go through the scanner separately.

The box and receipt are not part of the equation.

This of course assumes that the device fits within the airlines carry-on dimensions though I can't imagine a video card that wouldn't.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your answer. I guess I'll take it and hope for the best.